# How to set a time-driven trigger that goes at a specific hour and minute of the day? - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, triggers

I am trying to set a time-driven trigger for my script that extracts some values from a google sheet, then perform analysis, and then stores the analysis results in another google sheet.
In time-driven triggers, using 'Day Timer' only allows to choose from ranges like 8 to 9 AM or 5 - 6 PM, in the chosen range, the script will run automatically but on any time between that hour. I need it to run at exactly 8:15 AM every day.
I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Time-driven trigger feature of Google Apps Script does not allow specifying a fix time to run the script. I need to set a fix time (8:15) for time-driven trigger that in result, will run the script at that time.

Comment: Would you please summarise the research done before posting this question. The question is addressed by many users on StackOverflfow, and a variety of solutions are proposed. Which, if any, of these answers apply to your situation isn't clear but we don't need to unnecessarily reinvent the wheel .